# Use case for Python datetime.time class

Tags: python, time

I'm trying to think of a use case for `datetime.time` in Python 3. It may be my lack of imagination, but I'm struggling to come up with a use where either `datetime.datetime` or the `time` module aren't more appropriate.

An aware `time` object needs a date, because of DST. Much of the world doesn't use DST, but even so, using `datetime.time` would prevent conversion to local time in a timezone that does.

Any suggestions, no matter how esoteric, are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It could be used to format time, for if you have an application which gives you say an hour, minute, etc. in a list, then you use that to format it for a user. Ex. A stopwatch, it counts up by seconds, then you can seperate that into hours, minutes, and seconds, then use `datetime.time(hour=time["hour"], minute=time["minute"], second=time["second"]`.

Comment: I agree that using `datetime.datetime` would be a bit cludgy there - you'd have to use arbitrary values for day, month and year. However, the time would probably come in as either a Python time of some sort, or a string. For a string, strptime would give us a `time` time; with the added advantage that we could easily find the difference between 2 stopwatch values. `datetime.time` doesn't support subtraction, but the time module would let us subtract the results from `mktime` to get the difference.